# getting error StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: java

I am trying to build a matrix with row and column having values such as "aaa" for aligning purposes. but when I run it I get an error. below is my code

```
public class compute_matrix {
  static String seq1="aaa";
  static String seq2="aaa";
  static int[][] matrix;
  static int max_row;
  static int max_col;
  private static int match_reward=1;
  private static int mismatch_penalty= -1;
  private static int gap_cost= -1;
  private static boolean case_sensitive;

  private static boolean isCaseSensitive() {
    return case_sensitive;
  }

  private static int max(int ins, int sub, int del, int i) {
    if (ins > sub) {
        if (ins > del) {
            return ins > i? ins : i;
        } else {
            return del > i ?del : i;
        }
    } else if (sub > del) {
        return sub> i ? sub : i;
    } else {
        return del > i ? del : i;
    }
}

 protected char sequence[];

   public static void main(String args[]){
    int r, c, rows, cols, ins, sub, del, max_score;

    rows = seq1.length()+1;
    cols = seq2.length()+1;

    matrix = new int [rows][cols];

    // initiate first row
    for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        matrix[0][c] = 0;

    // keep track of the maximum score
    max_row = max_col = max_score = 0;

    // calculates the similarity matrix (row-wise)
    for (r = 1; r < rows; r++)
    {
        // initiate first column
        matrix[r][0] = 0;

        for (c = 1; c < cols; c++)
        {
                        sub = matrix[r-1][c-1] + scoreSubstitution(seq1.charAt(r),seq2.charAt(c));
            ins = matrix[r][c-1] + scoreInsertion(seq2.charAt(c));

            del = matrix[r-1][c] + scoreDeletion(seq1.charAt(r));

            // choose the greatest
            matrix[r][c] = max (ins, sub, del, 0);

            if (matrix[r][c] > max_score)
            {
                // keep track of the maximum score
                max_score = matrix[r][c];
                max_row = r; max_col = c;
            }
        }
    }
     }

private static int scoreSubstitution(char a, char b) {
   if (isCaseSensitive())
        if (a == b)
            return match_reward;
        else
            return mismatch_penalty;
    else
        if (Character.toLowerCase(a) == Character.toLowerCase(b))
            return match_reward;
        else
            return mismatch_penalty;
}

private static int scoreInsertion(char a) {
 return gap_cost;
}

private static int scoreDeletion(char a) {
    return gap_cost;
}
public char charAt (int pos)
{
    // convert from one-based to zero-based index
    return sequence[pos-1];
}

  }
```

and my error is displaying this

```
              Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
    at compute_matrix.main(compute_matrix.java:67)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: Are you a Visual Basic programmer learning Java?

Comment: You'd better debug your issue yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   rows = seq1.length()+1;
    cols = seq2.length()+1;

    matrix = new int [rows][cols];
```

and then later:

```
   for (c = 1; c < cols; c++)
    {
   //when c == cols-1, it is also `seq2.length()`
   //the access to seq2.charAt(c) will cause this exception then.
                    sub = matrix[r-1][c-1] + scoreSubstitution(seq1.charAt(r),seq2.charAt(c));
        ins = matrix[r][c-1] + scoreInsertion(seq2.charAt(c));

        del = matrix[r-1][c] + scoreDeletion(seq1.charAt(r));
```

In the above loop, when `c == cols-1`, it is also `seq2.length()`, the access to `seq2.charAt(c)` will cause this exception then.

You initialize the number of rows and cols to `length() + 1`, while you later iterate from 0 to length (inclusive), while the string contain only `length()` chars - from 0 to n exclusive.

If you are a C programmer in your past - I assume you are expecting a `\0` terminator at the end of the string. In java you don't have those - since `String` is an object - you can hold a field to indicate its exact length. Meaning the last char in the string, is actually the last character there.

Comment: i am quite new to java ...i am understanding what you are saying.but i can figure out how to change the code for it to work.....please help me

Comment: @SonalAkhal: I am not sure I am following the logic, but I suspect Initializing your sizes to `seq1.length()` and `seq2.length()`  (without the +1) will do...

Comment: Thanks amit it works still get a small problem but i know how how to fix it .Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

in line 60 of your code
`sub = matrix[r-1][c-1] + scoreSubstitution(seq1.charAt(r),seq2.charAt(c));`
max value for r is 4 so when you look up for seq.charAt(3) there is nothingso it shows index out of bound

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code into more canonical java.

The things I've changed:

- The class is now called `SimilarityMatrix`, a more appropriate, self documenting name
- variable declarations now happen where they get used as opposed to at the top of main
- The work is now done in an instance of the class rather than the main method
- I used the built in `Math.max(int, int)` instead of rolling my own
- I removed a lot of unnecessary nested if statements.  Java's short circuit evaluation helps here
- Since both `r` and `c` as well as `r+1` and `c+1` are used frequently in your calculation loop, I track both
- I removed many of the dependencies on static state (made many things instance variables)
- Static state that remains is all final now (I made them constants)
- Used more java-y variable names (java people really like their camel case)

```
public class SimilarityMatrix
{
    public static final int matchReward = 1;
    public static final int mismatchPenalty = -1;
    public static final int gapCost = -1;

    private int[][] matrix;
    private int maxRow = 0;
    private int maxCol = 0;
    private boolean caseSensitive = false;

    SimilarityMatrix(String s1, String s2, boolean dontIgnoreCase)
    {
        this(s1, s2);
        caseSensitive = dontIgnoreCase;
    }

    SimilarityMatrix(String s1, String s2)
    {
        int rows = s1.length() + 1;
        int cols = s2.length() + 1;
        matrix = new int[rows][cols];

        int max_score = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            matrix[0][x] = 0;
            matrix[x][0] = 0;
        }

        for (int r = 0, rp1 = 1; rp1 < rows; ++r, ++rp1)
        {
            for (int c = 0, cp1 = 1; cp1 < rows; ++c, ++cp1)
            {
                int sub = matrix[r][c] + scoreSubstitution(s1.charAt(r), s2.charAt(c));
                int ins = matrix[rp1][c] + scoreInsertion(s2.charAt(c));

                int del = matrix[r][cp1] + scoreDeletion(s1.charAt(r));

                // choose the greatest
                matrix[rp1][cp1] = Math.max(Math.max(ins, sub), Math.max(del, 0));

                if (matrix[rp1][cp1] > max_score)
                {
                    // keep track of the maximum score
                    max_score = matrix[rp1][cp1];
                    maxRow = rp1;
                    maxCol = cp1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SimilarityMatrix me = new SimilarityMatrix("aaa", "aaa");
        System.out.println(me.getMaxRow() + " " + me.getMaxCol());
    }

    private int scoreSubstitution(char a, char b)
    {
        if ((a == b && caseSensitive) || Character.toLowerCase(a) != Character.toLowerCase(b))
            return matchReward;
        else
            return mismatchPenalty;
    }

    public int getMaxRow()
    {
        return maxRow;
    }

    public int getMaxCol()
    {
        return maxCol;
    }

    private int scoreInsertion(char a)
    {
        return gapCost;
    }

    private int scoreDeletion(char a)
    {
        return gapCost;
    }
}
```

Comment: A note about style: yours is fine (though your indentation could use some work).  Generally, consistency is more important than semantics.  When you're working in groups, try to make your code look like whatever style is agreed upon by the group, even if you don't like it.  Except curly braces.  Those go on their own lines, period.